# parallel python timeout spawns another process instead of failing?

Tags: python, subprocess, parallel-python

Using parallel python 1.6.4 I spawn a subprocess.Popen command on a remote server.  For whatever reason, the command isn't completing in a timely matter, i.e., within the socket_timeout I've set.  In this case, I expected parallel python to fail, kill the remote process, and maybe raise an exception.  Instead, the long process keeps running, and the ppserver quietly spawns another one!

How can I configure ppserver to fail?

Short of that, I suppose I have to set timer, and destroy the job_server to make it close out and clean up the bad process?